# Elasticsearch index crashes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When the delete phase policy must delete the last index, it does not delete it and also adds the alias again.
I look at the aliases and i see clearly that it creates an alias conflict and my current index is blocked

GET _aliases

```
  "index-000113" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "index" : { }
    }
  },
  "index-000114" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  },
  "index-000115" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  },
  "index-000116" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "index" : { }
    }
  },
```

My configuration have 3 nodes , 1 master and 2 slaves.
My solution is to manually delete the index that should be deleted by the deletion policy

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "index-000113",
        "alias": "index"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My last shard Activity in kibana

index-000113
Shard: 0 / Replica
Recovery type: Peer
Done
(node01 > node03)

index-000113
Shard: 0 / Primary
Recovery type: Existing_store
Done
(n/a >  node03)

It seems that the last activity has something to do with it that I don't know what it means.
anyone know why it happens and any solution?

I looked in the official documentation but i can't find why happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [_aliases API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) [remove](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases-api-request-body) action is not remove the `index` but `alias`. To remove the index you can use `remove_index` action.

```
add - Adds a data stream or index to an alias. If the alias doesn’t exist, the add action creates it.
remove -  Removes a data stream or index from an alias.
remove_index - Deletes an index. You cannot use this action on aliases or data streams.
```

check the followings:

1. Check ILM policy `GET _ilm/policy/<policy_id>`
2. Use explain index ILM policy API `GET <index_name>/_ilm/explain`
3. Test the rollover with dry_run `POST <index_pattern>/_rollover?dry_run=true` your index pattern is **index**.

The alias named `index` looks like your write_alias. When the index rolled over the alias must be switch to the latest index. If not try to add [is_write_index: true](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases-api-request-body) to the index template. If you stuck again create another [rollover index and start from scratch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-rollover-index.html#roll-over-index-alias-with-write-index).